# Nodejs mapping through an API gives error: Cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

I'm trying to process data from an API. (I have no control over the API output).
Here's an example of the code :

```
const json = [
  {
    c: [
      { v: 'Product 1' },
      { v: '1234102' },
      { v: 'IN STOCK' },
      null,
      { v: 'Access From All Warehouses' },
    ],
  },
  {
    c: [
      { v: 'Product 2' },
      { v: '1234608' },
      { v: 'OUT OF STOCK' },
      { v: '6/2022' },
      { v: 'Access From All Warehouses' },
    ],
  },
  { c: [{ v: 'Category Name' }, null, null, null, { v: null }] },
  {
    c: [
      { v: 'Product 3' },
      { v: '1234942' },
      { v: 'OUT OF STOCK' },
      { v: 'No ETA ' },
      { v: 'Access From All Warehouses' },
    ],
  },
];
const result = json.map((row) => {
  return {
    name: row.c[0].v,
     sku: row.c[1].v,
     inventory: row.c[2].v,
     eta: row.c[3].v,
     access: row.c[4].v,
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

When I get to the category name or a product with missing information the map function gives an error of "Cannot read properties of null".  What is a good solution to bypass that issue?

I've tried using somethinhg like:

```
sku: row.c[1].v || '',
```

but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
sku: row.c[1]?.v || '',
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the ? in other places, didn't think about using it there!  I'll mark you as answer as soon as the system lets me.

Comment: if you're already using optional chaining you may as well also leverage the [nullish coallescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). `sku: row.c[1]?.v ?? '',`